Ho to use CMSIS-Core (Cortex-M) for TM4C123GH6PM and TM4C129ENCPDT in Code Composer Studio
I'm trying to write drivers for TM4C129ENCPDT and TM4C123GH6PM in Code Composer Studio(Linux). I prefer to use CMSIS and not Tivaware. I'm unable to get the CMSIS-Core Device Files (provided by silicon vendor - Texas Instruments) and CMSIS-Core Standard Files (provided by ARM).
I've used Tivaware for the drivers and prefer to use CMSIS going forward.
Please advice on getting started with the same.
Also did I go wrong with choosing Code Composer Studio? TI has come up with Theia IDE recently. Shall I switch to Theia or any other IDE or any other toolchain?
